# Is there a C# equivalent to boost::interprocess::basic_string?

Tags: c#, c++, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files, boost-interprocess

In C++, using boost::interprocess you can define a boost::interprocess::basic_string which is basically an abstraction over a string that's stored in a Memory Mapped File. You can seamlessly use it like any other string in your application (assuming of course you take care of thread safety).

Is there any equivalent library/nuget package/piece of code for C#?

Comment: There's nothing in that Boost class that makes it especially suited in an MMF.  Strings in C++ are just a nightmare, every non-trivial library is forced to add its own because it can't rely on the implementation details of another.  Don't repeat that mistake, use Encoding.GetBytes().

Comment: @HansPassant But I can use a boost::interprocess::allocator that allocated that string in MMF, and can even place those strings in a data-structure that's stored in MMF such as a boost::interprocess::map or boost::interprocess::vector. I'm looking for a similar abstraction in C#, one that abstracts away dealing with streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. However, even if it were possible to implement transparently, strings in C# are immutable. Therefore I don't think having a library quite like that would be even very useful.